# Get the project which has been modified in a git repository

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

so i m trying to create a pipeline for continuous delivery in Jenkins. My first step is to import the git repository to my Jenkins server. To give an idea my git repository is hosted on a bitbucket server ( for eg testrepository.git). Now within this repository the structure is as follows

Testrepository.git

- project 1
- project 2
- project 3

My aim is to get the list of projects which have been modified and build only those in my pipeline. Is there a way to achieve this ? All the projects are java projects with gradle build file

Comment: Assuming there's a good reason to keep your project/repo structure like this, I would do something by using `git log --stat` to get modified files and compare them against individual project file lists. I'm not too familiar with Gradle, but I think you should have something in your Gradle config that tracks all files or directories included in a project.

Comment: @Pockets are you saying to manually check the output of the above command and then build the specific project? is there a way to get it using any script ? i would want to automate the process. Also there are several projects (~50) and inter dependent. Hence this repo structure.

Comment: No, I'm saying that you should be able to script an automated comparison between the output of `git log` and individual project file lists, and use that to determine how Jenkins triggers new builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git log --name-only` will show you the filename list modified in each commit. you can analyse filename list to judge which project was modified.

If you do continuous delivery, you can get modified file list from last delivery
by the following command, suppose "2016-11-10 16:00" is your last delivery timestamp.

```
git diff $(git rev-list -n 1 --before="2016-11-10 16:00" HEAD) --name-only
```